# ngx-numeric-textbox with comma as decimal separator

Tags: angular

I have angular 6 app. I want have comma as decimal separator and two digits as decimal part in input box.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-numeric-textbox

http://numeraljs.com/#format

How set corret format? I tried with this '$0,0.00', but I still get 1 000.23
1000.234    '$0,0.00'   €1 000,23

I want have something like this:
1000,23
or 
1.000,23

Comment: this is the case for a custom pipe

Comment: Can I use pipe in input text?

Comment: is the solution below working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

focusout might be the best time to update the input... This should give what you're trying to achieve

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="InputStr" (focusout)="InputChange()" />
```

**app.component.ts**

```
InputChange(){
    console.log(this.InputStr);
    var event:any = this.InputStr;
    if(event.length>0){
      this.wholePart = Math.floor(event);
      this.decimalPart = event.toString().replace(/^[^\.]+/,'0').toString().substring(2,6);
      this.InputStr = this.wholePart+ "," + this.decimalPart;
    }
   }
```

complete [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lgopey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) here